# Loop Selenium through List of Web pages

Tags: java, loops, selenium

I'm working with Selenium Webdriver in Eclipse.  I want it to open

```
http://www.sample.com/catalog?product_id="0001"
```

**fill fields and check radial buttons** and  then close and then loop open

```
http://www.sample.com/catalog?product_id="0002"`
```

and execute the same actions. I would like it to loop until it reaches `9990`.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","/Users/Downloads/geckodriver");
WebDriver driver;
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
String base = ("http://www.sample.com/catalog?product_id="0001");
```

Comment: Search for Data driven testing in TestNg / Junit. Here is an example for TestNg [link](http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2014/05/webdriver-test-data-driven-testing.html)

Comment: So what have you tried to accomplish the loop? Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

**Code snippet:**

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 9990; i++){
        String base = "http://www.sample.com/catalog?product_id=" + String.format("%04d", i);   
        driver.get(base);
       //do your stuff here
  }
```

Above code snippet will build your URL as you wanted and land on the required page.